# Can I plot two geom_segments, displaced to each other by group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to produce a figure with arrows depicting the magnitude between two values by sex. I naturally want the two arrows to be displaced to each other.

```
data <- data.frame(sex  = c('Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Women','Women','Women','Women','Women'),
                    age = c('00-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '00-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89'),
                    obs_1 = c(42.73, 12.97, 11.87, 10.34, 5.39, 49.29 , 17.69, 14.41, 10.80, 6.49),
                    obs_2 = c(15.88, 28.16, 25.98, 25.55, 18.91,21.57, 38.28, 35.28, 30.10, 23.09)
                  )
```

Using geom_segment I get the arrows that I want but they will ofc be on top of each other

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color = sex)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = obs_1, xend = obs_2,
                   y = age, yend = age), linewidth = 1.2, 
               arrow = arrow(type = 'closed', length = unit(3.5, 'mm')) 
  )
```

I know that similar issues have been addressed in here and a solution is to use geom_linerange with position_dodge2, but then I cannot get the arrows that I am after.

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age, color = sex,
                 ymin = obs_1,
                 ymax = obs_2)) +
  geom_linerange(linewidth = 1, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_segment` is often used with continuous scales so you could have age as a continuous variable and manually add a little space based on sex.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(sex  = c('Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Men', 'Women','Women','Women','Women','Women'),
                   age = c('00-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '00-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89'),
                   obs_1 = c(42.73, 12.97, 11.87, 10.34, 5.39, 49.29 , 17.69, 14.41, 10.80, 6.49),
                   obs_2 = c(15.88, 28.16, 25.98, 25.55, 18.91,21.57, 38.28, 35.28, 30.10, 23.09)) %>%
  mutate(age=factor(age),
         age2=as.numeric(age)+c(Men=.1, Women=-0.1)[sex])

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = sex)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = obs_1, xend = obs_2, y = age2, yend = age2),
               linewidth = 1.2,
               arrow = arrow(type = 'closed', length = unit(3.5, 'mm'))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq_len(nlevels(data$age)), labels=levels(data$age))
```

[image: example plot with dodged arrows]